Movie where high school girl sails away in sailboat with money
I remember watching  a movie several years ago in the US, in color. Seemed like it came out in the 80s or early 90s. 
I only really remember the ending which is a spoiler!!
I believe the main characters consisted of a male high school teacher and two female students. The teacher was sleeping with one/both possibly. Took place near the ocean (sailed away in end so I'd hope so)
At the end, it seemed the teacher was the mastermind behind everything and was going to get away with whatever he did, along side one of the students. But I think one student ended up being killed by him (he got greedy) and he was going to kill the other, but it turns out she is the mastermind and steals the money from him. 
He thought she was reliant on him to drive the sailboat away (their getaway) but he finds out she is a master at sailing and so she ditches him.
The movie ends with her sailing away on a nice sailboat with the money. 

Some details about character appearances I remember:

One female student was blond, pretty, popular type
Other female student was quiet, weird, I think she had brown, curly hair

Sorry it is so vague, been a long time.  

I think this is Wild Things (1998) with Denise Richards and Neve Campbell

Wikipedia

A popular Miami area high school guidance counselor, Sam Lombardo, is accused of rape by two female students, the wealthy and popular girl named Kelly Van Ryan and poor girl named Suzie Toller, and hires lawyer Kenneth Bowden to defend him. At trial, Suzie admits that she and Kelly had made everything up to get revenge on Lombardo: Suzie for him failing to bail her out of jail on a minor drug charge and Kelly for him having an affair with her mother, Sandra. Kelly's mother is humiliated by the scandal, and Lombardo and Bowden negotiate an $8.5 million settlement for defamation. In reality, Lombardo and the two girls were accomplices who used the trial as a way to get money from Kelly's wealthy family.



Sam returns to his beach bungalow to find Duquette taking a shower. They were partners, setting everyone up so they could split the money just two ways. Although Lombardo is not pleased that Duquette killed Kelly instead of framing her as originally planned, he agrees that they now have fewer loose ends. The two agree to go fishing on Lombardo's sailboat, where Lombardo tries to eliminate Duquette. When Duquette fights back, he is shot and killed by a very much alive Suzie. 




